# column "st_srid" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.3

Hi I'm executing this query in my java code and it tells me

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "st_srid" does not exist

However when I run it directly in pgAdmin it shows me the column and the value inside.

Here is my query:

```
"Select Distinct ST_SRID(shape) from TableName where shape IN (SELECT shape from TableName)"
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly. You don't need distinct because a geometry only has one (or none if none are defined) and the IN clause seems redundant. What do you get when you do `select srid from geometry_columns where f_table_name='TableName'`

Comment: @JohnBarça I'm trying to get the srid of a column however I don't want to use Find_SRID since i dont have access to schema name in my code. If I don't put distinct it returns so many rows of 4326. here shape is my geometry column. And I don't think your query is correct how can write from column? shouldnt it be a table? and also what do you mean by f_table_name

Comment: geometry_columns is a view. If you looked at geometry_columns you would understand. So, if you get many rows of 4326, then that is your answer: a geometry can only have one SRID. Your in clause is still meaningless, as it just repeats what is in your where clause. However, I repeat, the query I have posted is correct, and will give you a single answer for the srid of the geometry column for a particular table. I suggest you try it rather than telling me I am wrong.

Comment: @JohnBarça my problem is in java postgresql9.3 returns this error ERROR: column "st_srid" does not exist. It's seems like it doesn't have this function implemented.

Comment: You do have the Postgis functions installed? You can run something like select st_makepoint(0,0);

Comment: @JohnBarça yea I can execute things like st_distance,ST_Transform and ST_GeomFromText, etc

Comment: OK, so if you issue this from Java, and there is no srid set on the goemetry, then you will get zero rows, which would lead to that error if you then tried to read the value?

Comment: The query is fine. The problem is probably hidden elsewhere in Java. The result column named "st_srid" is not to be confused with the PostGIS function ST_SRID.

Comment: **Show your code** please.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct needs parenthesis around the `st_srid` function call.